# Microsoft webchat in french

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I have embed the Microsoft web chat channel into my site using the iFrame methode :
    https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/mybot?s=YOUR_SECRET_HERE'>

The web chat interface is in english, what parameters do I need to get the french version ? (the microsoft framework says french is supported).

Answer (score 0):

French is supported in the Framework yes, it does not mean everything will be in French everywhere.

It is supported because you can use French language to talk to the bot. For example in the `Prompt` class, when you use a `PromptConfirm` will understand when you reply with `oui` or `non`.

For the Webchat interface, if you need to customize anything, have a look to the github project about webchat here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat

You will find all the necessary items to search if you can setup what you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

To localize the content of your bot you need to configure the default locale in your bot code, and provide resource files that define the default messaging in your language.  All of this happens in your bot code and not in WebChat. The WebChat control is just the delivery mechanism for your bot's messages.

For more information on localization in Bot Framework:

- .NET SDK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow-localize
- Node SDK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-localization

Code Examples:

- .NET SDK: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/AnnotatedSandwichBot
- Node SDK: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/Node/examples/basics-localization